# Using ADB to run React Native on-device (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

In the React Native documentation (0.40) ["Running on Device"](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) for iOS on MacOS, it suggests using `adb reverse` to connect to the development server over USB. This method is, in fact, the recommended method.

I understand this works for Android, but I wasn't aware it would work for iOS devices. Whenever I try `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` as per the docs, it gives me `error: no devices/emulators found`.

After searching on Google for using adb with iOS/iPhone, I wasn't getting anything. I also didn't find anything on React Native's issues regarding it, and Stack Overflow's [closest thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430181/adb-equivalent-for-ios-device) is related to debugging with adb, not running React Native (or iOS generally) through USB using adb.

Does anyone have any experience using this method successfully?

Comment: I think this is a documentation error. The same section appears in the Android version, where it's probably appropriate. `adb` is definitely only used with Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by jcaron, there was an issue in the doc, `adb` is Android specific.

[A pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11625) was sent and accepted a few days ago.

The changes are already reflected in the next version: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: Thanks! Pity there isn't a nice way to do debugging over USB for iOS, but hopefully that'll save someone else the head scratching I had over this.