# is there similar to Android ADB commands for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, adb

I create an app with C# to generate several ADB commands for android devices, but now I´m trying to do the same with iOS, I want to be able to make tap, swips, etc, using the same app in C# in my windows PC.

Comment: Maybe this can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430181/adb-equivalent-for-ios-device

Comment: I saw it but the resolutions is using Mac, and I trying to use windows.